# How to set custom @timestamp in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I am using AWS managed ELK setup (ver 6.4.3). As per my understanding, Kibana uses @timestamp field to sort the data.

I have a field by name 'ts' (in epoch millis). I want to convert the format of 'ts' to that of @timestamp and want to use 'ts' field as the default in place of @timestamp.

I tried searching about it. It was related to using templates but couldnt really understand much there!

It would be great if anyone could help me here with the same.
Thanks!

Comment: When creating your index pattern in Kibana, you can decide which field to use as the timestamp, it must not necessarily be called `@timestamp`, you can definitely pick your `ts` field for that.

Comment: Val I have already created the index pattern with @timestamp. Is there a way to reset the pattern properties?

Comment: You can delete the index pattern and recreate it, that operation won't affect your underlying indexes

Comment: Val, I tried doing the same but I don't see any field other than @timestamp in the drop down!